# Free app to write reps, weighs, sets and see progression?

Tags: bodybuilding, weight-gain

This app should handle this case:
My first squat set is 7 reps failure at 120kg, then 10s rest pause, then 2 reps failure at 120kg then 10s rest pause, then 9 reps failure at 100kg,then 10s rest pause, then 13 reps failure at 80.
Then I do 3 other sets like this set.

Is there any android app to save these performances? And see a graph month after month?

Comment: Just wondering, what's your setup? Do you use multiple squat racks, or how do you manage to deload 20kg off the bar within 10 seconds after muscle failure?

Comment: I'm not sure what "7 reps failure", "9 reps failure" is. Are you missing a "/" in the middle? And I see that you are still ignoring the advice to find a basic program and stick with it...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bad subjective question - From the help section - "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …

every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”"

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to handle something like this with FitNotes. It allows you to add custom exercises and it graphs the progression of that individual exercise over time. This includes max weight, max volume, estimated 1rm, max reps, and a few others I can't remember off the top of my head.

So in this case you'd add an exercise like "Barbell Squat: 10s drop set". Set it as a leg exercise (or whatever category you want. You can add custom categories too). Then set it for a weights/reps schema. You'll just then log the weights and reps you do. It'll tell you when you get rep PRs and track the history.

You can't log rest times though. It only works because it's 10 seconds each time.

Answer (score 0):

Simple workout log is one.
Beyond the whiteboard is another one.

However, none answers my personal needs. If a willing web developer comes here, I would be willing to speak with him about my ideas for developing a website behaving like a true fitness journal

Answer (score 0):

I have my workout programmed into Google Sheets. It is an excel clone. It is fairly easy to format and set up on the computer and then I can see it on my phone through the Google Sheets app at the gym.

Once you have your data in an excel format you can make whatever graphs you want. Granted, this would require more input on your end.